# Execute SQL Scripts inside Azure Repos folder incrementally and sequentially on Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database

I am trying to execute SQL scripts present inside a folder in my Azure Repos in a required sequence and also incrementally.

I tried to use DACPAC approach for same but it only creates tables, procedures...so on, incrementally but do not execute DML commands such as INSERT,UPDATE etc. But I want to create tables, procedures incrementally and sequentially as well as run DML queries (INSERT, UPDATE...) on them. Is their any other approach for this use case.

Comment: Do you use DB project in Visual Studio?

Comment: I used the DB project in Azure Data Studio